# Parameter effective visibility conflict between java and kotlin

Tags: java, android, visibility, kotlin, materialdrawer

I'm trying to override `bindView` function:

```
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem

open class SpinnerDrawerItem() : PrimaryDrawerItem(), View.OnClickListener {
  override fun bindView(viewHolder: ViewHolder?) {
    super.bindView(viewHolder)
    // Do things
  }
}
```

From [PrimaryDrawerItem](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/355f1dd99484192c7fbdb228ea94fb3cef585b1f/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/drawerItems/CustomPrimaryDrawerItem.java) but I get:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PrimaryDrawerItem.ViewHolder` is `protected`. And the `bindView()` method, which is `public`, accepts `PrimaryDrawerItem.ViewHolder`. But a general external caller cannot invoke this method because it cannot refer a `protected` nested class `PrimaryDrawerItem.ViewHolder`. Kotlin prohibits such behavior and requires either to make the parameter visibility equal to the method visibility or to decrease the parameter visibility to be less or equal to the method visibility.

In your case you have to make `PrimaryDrawerItem.ViewHolder` `public` or make `PrimaryDrawerItem.bindView()` protected.

Comment: Just started a pull request for this https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/pull/1200 thanks